# Возникла проблема при установке библиотеки tgbot

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

Библиотека вроде поставилась, но в дальнейшем вылетает ошибка:

```
CMake Error at D:/oop/1/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY
  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: так, как написано: `try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR`

Comment: По какой инструкции действуете?

Comment: https://github.com/reo7sp/tgbot-cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте указать в CMakeLists.txt:
`find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)`
`include_directories(<путь до vcpkg>/installed/<необходимый триплет>/include ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR}`
Далее при линковке библиотеки укажите в качестве аргумента  `${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}`

Answer (score 0):

Стоит попробовать установить или обновить OpenSSL

`vcpkg install openssl:x64-windows`

А также, что находится в CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: openssl установлен